# How do you send an object to the back of the displaylist?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, flash-cs6

My object should be no longer viewable as it should be under everything in the scene.  However this does not happen.

Inside Constructor Function:

I've tried:

```
this.parent.setChildIndex(this, 0);
```

Nothing happens.  Then I thought, "I wonder if the object's position really is 0."

So I checked by doing this:

```
trace(this.parent.getChildIndex(this));
```

Output:

```
0
```

Since this is clearly not working, how do I set my object to the bottom of the display list?

EDIT:

I have tried this except from a `MouseEvent.CLICK`

Constructor Function:

```
addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
```

onClick Function:

```
public function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    this.parent.setChildIndex(this, 0);
    trace(this.parent.getChildIndex(this));
}
```

Output:

```
0
```

Comment: You probably should not do it in the constructor. Try next frame with ENER_FRAME listener once.

Comment: I updated the post to include the same thing, but not done in the constructor.

Comment: I have a feeling the issue is related to the object's parent not being the stage.  But if that is the problem, I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: If object's parent is not on stage, you won't be able to see the object at all. Do you take into account that **setChildIndex** works **inside** container while that container is on top of its designated siblings?

Comment: What is the output for trace (this.parent.numChildren)? If it is 1, it's the parent movieclip (or parent.parent) where you should set the getChildIndex